# How to launch application with rofi using i3wm's exec?

Tags: i3, exec, application, launcher, rofi

I had [this issue](https://github.com/i3/i3/discussions/4782) and now I know how to solve it. I need to launch applications with **i3wm**'s `exec` command.

ButI use **rofi** as launchmenu and I have no idea how to make it lauch applications with **i3wm**'s `exec` command ?

I have binded **rofi** menu using this config:

```
 bindsym $mod+space exec --no-startup-id rofi -show combi -show-icons
```

How can I chive it ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to change my i3 config rofi call to this:

```
bindsym $mod+space exec --no-startup-id rofi -show combi -run-command "i3-msg exec '{cmd}'" -show-icons
```

Answer (score 2):

To launch `rofi` using i3, you have to set a key binding with `exec` in your i3 config:

```
bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id rofi -show drun
```

`$mod` is set to your modifier key (e.g., Alt or Super).

The key binding will open your application list in `rofi` where you can select and launch your applications.

Comment: I have no problem launching application. The problem is I want them to launch throw i3's exec. I do not think your suggestion does that.

Comment: It is not clear how you want to launch your applications. If you want to use `rofi` then you would launch applications from `rofi`'s application list. If you want to simply use `exec` in i3 to launch applications directly then `rofi` is not needed. Example to launch Firefox: `bindsym $mod+F1 exec firefox`

Comment: The point is when I launch application using rofi it is equivalent as running it from terminal. So if I launch `arandr` using rofi it same as runnig `arandr` in terminal. But I want to make it so launching it from rofi would be equivalent to `i3-msg exec arandr`